# railsr.com KYC check for Play Environment

Tags: environment, live

I'm curious if anyone has experience with railsr.com or has integrated their APIs before. I have a question regarding their KYC API, which seems to only function in the LIVE environment. While I understand the rationale behind this decision, I'm wondering how developers can effectively test the KYC process during app development with railsr.com.

Thanks!

There is nothing available for railsr.com on stackoverflow; not a single post and I came up with this question.